# Async stored procedure call in Web API 2 using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

In our company, we create Web APIs using synchronous database interactions using stored procedures. I recently read the Microsoft docs which said that asynchronous APIs should be the default (I'll leave the theory). I also know that if async is not implemented correctly, you get a sync method + extra overhead.

My questions:

- Is my adapted code actually async?
- If not, how can I make it async?
- Is there a way to verify if this code is async?

Original code:

```
public class EventsController : ApiController 
{
    EventCapturingToolDBEntities _db = new DBEntities(); 

    IhttpActionResult GetProjectsByUserId(int userId)
    {
        results = _db.getProjectsByUserId(userId).AsQueryable.ToList(); //Stored procedure generated by EF after database first approach
        var processResults = //resultsprocessing
        return Ok(processResults)
    }
}
```

Adapted code:

```
public class EventsController : ApiController 
{
    private EventCapturingToolDBEntities _db = new DBEntities(); 

    public async Task<IhttpActionResult> GetProjectsByUserId(int userId)
    {
        var results = await _db.Database
                               .SqlQuery<getProjectsByUserId_Result>("getProjectsByUserId @p0", userId).ToListAsync(); //Class generated by EF as part of the stored procedure
        var processResults = //resultsprocessing
        return Ok(processResults)
    }
} //Is this async?
```

Comment: The way to verify it ... as anything .. is to debug it and observe what happens.

Comment: I did that, and both behaved exactly the same way. I do not know if that means they behave as they should, or if the "async" method is actually synchronous

Comment: Unsure if this is Stackoverflow format, but it is correct and async.

Comment: When you add the `async` keyword to your original method without further changes then you will see the CS1998 warning: 'This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. etc.'. So it safe to assume that otherwise the method runs asynchronously.